# ng-repeat table <br> tag

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I put `ng-repeat` in my table because I'm doing a multiple table here's whats look like,

[image]

and I don't know where to put the `<br>` tag to make them separate every repeat of the table

Here is my view (slim format)

```
table.md-table ng-repeat="(key, value) in search.leave_applications | groupBy:'employee.name'"
tr.md-table-headers-row
  th.md-table-header name
  th.md-table-header start
  th.md-table-header end
  th.md-table-header status
tr.md-table-headers-row
  td.md-table-headers-row
    | {{key}}
  td.md-table-headers-row colspan="3"
tr.md-table-headers-row ng-repeat=" date in value"
  td.md-table-headers-row
  td.md-table-headers-row
    | {{date.starts_on}}
  td.md-table-headers-row
    | {{date.ends_on}}
  td.md-table-headers-row stats
```

Comment: Why don't you try to use css for table instead of <br>? Something like style="margin-top:20px"....

Comment: I'm not 100% that a `<br/>` tag between table rows would have the desired effect, if I am understanding you correctly.

Comment: @DonerKebab it will be adjust only the top of the table not the each table